# Remote debug a linux app from XCode

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, macos, debugging

it's simple i had this linux pc which i connect remote and i have this application that i run there and i want to debug it, but i just don't know how.
It's the simpler c++ app on the world, load some libraries, do some calculus, print some output and return,

It's just that, i just haven't any clue.

So any help would be appreciated. Thxs anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Xcode for this - just use `gdb` (which is what Xcode uses under the GUI anyway).

[You *might* be able to do it indirectly, if you build and debug the code on your Mac, but that assumes that you're not doing anything non-portable (i.e. Linux-specific) in the code, and there aren't any other platform-specific dependencies (e.g. third party libraries, etc). You would still need to do final test and debug on the Linux machine but at least you could potentially squash any logic bugs on the Mac first.]